# Benchmarking loading and execution time of iframes from specific initiator/origin

Tags: javascript, node.js, iframe, benchmarking, puppeteer

I have a website with a master script X. This script loads external scripts (async) depending on the pagetype, each of those scripts is separated in it's own iframe but those scripts may load other scripts. The website has a lot of pages that needs to be benchmarked and thus the process needs to be automated.

The website itself, the master script X and the iframes can't be changed.

The website loads other scripts/images which are not relevant but influence the loading+execution time of the specific iframes with origin X.

I need to know the loading and execution times of those iframes in absolute and relative time (e.g. master script X loads after 300ms on the page, takes 50ms to execute, loads iframe1, iframe1 loads after 350ms and takes 100ms to execute, loads another script that loads after 450ms and takes 30ms = iframe 1 starts after 350ms and finishes after 480ms - repeat for every other iframe with origin X).

Is this possible with Node.js / Puppeteer and if so, which functions/libs can I utilize for the task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox and Chrome offer to download the HAR archiv of the loaded website. It's a JSON file with all requests, sources, targets and loading times.

I can't put my source code online because I don't own the copyright but analysing this text file enables everything I needed (used recursive looping to get the unknown number of initiator depth requests).

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Listen to the according events, save the their time and calculate the results
2. Use an existing library to generate a HAR file

### Option 1: Listen to events

You can listen to events like [`request`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.14.0/docs/api.md#event-request), [`response`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.14.0/docs/api.md#event-response) (or [`requestfinished`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.14.0/docs/api.md#event-requestfinished)) in puppeteer, note their timestamps (e.g. by using `Date.now()`) and compare them. You have the full freedom (and responsibility) on what events to listen to.

**Example:**

```js
page.on('request', request => {
    if (request.url() === 'URL of your frame') {
        const timestamp = Date.now();
        // store time somewhere
    }
});
// listen to other events and store their timings in addition
```

Depending on the complexity of your page you might want to use arrays to store the data or even a database.

### Option 2: HAR file

Use a library like [puppeteer-har](https://github.com/Everettss/puppeteer-har) or [chrome-har](https://github.com/sitespeedio/chrome-har) to create a HAR file of the page loading process (I have not used any of these myself).

**Quotation what a HAR file is** ([source](https://blog.stackpath.com/glossary/har-file/)):

> The HAR file format is an evolving standard and the information contained within it is both flexible and extensible. You can expect a HAR file to include a breakdown of timings including:
>
> 1. How long it takes to fetch DNS information
> 2. How long each object takes to be requested
> 3. How long it takes to connect to the server
> 4. How long it takes to transfer assets from the server to the browser of each object
>
> The data is stored as a JSON document and extracting meaning from the
>   low-level data is not always easy. But with practice a HAR file can
>   quickly help you identify the key performance problems with a web
>   page, letting you efficiently target your development efforts at areas
>   of your site that will deliver the greatest results.

There are multiple existing tools to visualize HAR files ([like this one](http://www.softwareishard.com/har/viewer/)) and you can even [drop a HAR file into a Chrome instance](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/08/devtools-release-notes#har-imports) to analyze it.

If you want to automate the process even more, you can also write your own script to parse the HAR file. As it is a JSON file this is easy to do.

Comment: Option 1: Would I need to add this snippet to the website itself? I don't have access to the server itself/can't change the source code on that website. Problem is that the iframe script often loads more content that may load more content so I need to trace the initiators initiators initiator, several steps deep but not consistent. So I think the HAR approach seems more fitting for my use case.

Comment: @Vega No, you don't need to add the code to the page. It is exemplary puppeteer code.

Comment: The HAR Viewer does not show the sources of the request so not useable. Chrome of course does but you can't filter for it so you have to review every request by hand if the source matches.